# Passing List from View to Controller - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am now kind of stuck here.

I have my Models here

namespace DSS.Models

```
{
    public class SupplierItems
    {
        public string GroupID { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public List<SupplierLineItems> LineItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and have Properties of Supplier Items are defined in Model as

```
 namespace DSS.Models
    {
        public class SupplierLineItems
        {


                 public string Frequency { get; set; }
                 public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
                 public int Index { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

My Controller is just hardcoding the Supplier Items and line items

```
 namespace DSS.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
           [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult GetLineItems(SupplierItems SupplierItems)
            {
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult Index()
            {


                List<SupplierLineItems> ListOfLineItems = new List<SupplierLineItems>();
                SupplierLineItems LineItems = new SupplierLineItems();
                LineItems.Frequency = "Regulate";
                LineItems.UnitPrice = "20";
                LineItems.Index = 1;

                ListOfLineItems.Add(LineItems);

                SupplierLineItems LineItems1 = new SupplierLineItems();
                LineItems1.Frequency = "Regulate";
                LineItems1.UnitPrice = "20";
                LineItems.Index = 2;

                ListOfLineItems.Add(LineItems1);


                SupplierItems Items = new SupplierItems();
                Items.GroupID = "1";
                Items.GroupName = "Core Group";
                Items.LineItems = ListOfLineItems;


                return View(Items);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my View

```
@model DSS.Models.SupplierItems
@using DSS.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    {

       <a  type="submit" href="@Url.Action("GetLineItems", "Home", Model)">@Model.GroupName</a> 


         <br />

       foreach (var item in Model.LineItems)
      {     
            @item.Frequency<br />
            @item.UnitPrice<br />
            @item.Index<br /> 

       }

     }

}
```

When I click on Anchor tag of my view and pass the Model to "GetLineItems" of Home Controller, My Supplier items get passed successfully but List of Line items always comes as null. I am not sure what is going wrong . Anyone, please help

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax post to the controller or simply use form submission to achieve this
instead of using url.action which is an url form of submission